# Let $V$ and $W$ be vectors spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $L_\mathbb{R}(V,W) = L_\mathbb{C}(V,W) \oplus L_\mathbb{\overline{C}}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> $L_\mathbb{R}(V,W) = \mathbb{R}$-linear transformations from $V$ to $W$
>
> $L_\mathbb{C}(V,W) =  \mathbb{C}$-linear transformations from $V$ to $W$
>
> $L_\mathbb{\overline{C}}(V,W) =  \mathbb{C}$-anti linear transformations from $V$ to $W$

I was able to show that:
$$L_\mathbb{C}(V,W) \oplus L_\mathbb{\overline{C}}(V,W) \subset L_\mathbb{R}(V,W)$$ $$L_\mathbb{C}(V,W) \cap L_\mathbb{\overline{C}}(V,W) = \{0\}$$

I need to prove that:
$$L_\mathbb{R}(V,W) \subset L_\mathbb{C}(V,W) \oplus L_\mathbb{\overline{C}}(V,W) $$

What I have so far is:  for $L \in L_\mathbb{R}(V,W)$, we have:

$L(u) = \frac{T_1(u) + T_2(u)}{2} \quad \text{where:} \quad T_1(u) = L(u) + iL(u) \quad \text{and} \quad T_2(u) = L(u) - iL(u)$

I tried to prove that $T_1 \in L_\mathbb{C}(V,W) $ or  $T_1 \in L_\mathbb{\overline{C}}(V,W) $ but I couldn't see a clear way to do it.

Any hints?

Comment: What can you say about $x \mapsto L(x) \pm i L(ix)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An $\mathbb R$-linear map $T$ from $V$ to $W$ is $\mathbb C$-linear iff
$T(v)=-iT(iv)$ for all $v\in V$.

An $\mathbb R$-linear map $T$ from $V$ to $W$ is $\mathbb C$-antilinear iff
$T(v)=iT(iv)$ for all $v\in V$.

Define a map $T\mapsto T^*$ from $L_{\mathbb R}(V,W)$ to itself by letting
$T^*(v)=-iT(iv)$. Then $T\mapsto T^*$ is $\mathbb R$-linear and $(T^*)^*=T$.
Thus it's an involution. Therefore $L_{\mathbb R}(V,W)$ is the
direct sum of the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenspaces of this star map. But these
eigenspaces are $L_{\mathbb C}(V,W)$ and $L_{\overline{\mathbb{C}}}(V,W)$
respectively.